# Bigquery select records where array column in array value by 'And' condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have Bigquery table `name_fruits` like this...

```
| name | fruits |
|------|--------|
| aaaa | [apple, orange, grape] |
| bbbb | [apple, orange] |
| cccc | [orange, grape] |
| dddd | [orange] |
| eeee | [orange, peach] |
```

I am trying to select names that who has fruits both `apple` and `orange`.
Which means I want to select `aaaa` and `bbbb`.

The query needs to be dynamic. Can't hardcode `apple` and `orange` in the query.

Is there any solution to select them?

```
SELECT name
FROM name_fruits, UNNEST(fruits) fruit
WHERE fruit IN UNNEST(@find_fruits) # IN query can only "OR" search condition
AND ARRAY_LENGTH(fruits) >= ARRAY_LENGTH(@find_fruits)

# @find_fruits = ["apple", "orange"]
#
# => aaaa, bbbb, cccc, eeee
# I want => aaaa, bbbb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do this with variables.  Hence:

```
SELECT nf.*
FROM name_fruits nf
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) 
       FROM UNNEST(nf.fruits) fruit JOIN
            UNNEST(@find_fruits) ff
            ON ff = fruit
      ) >= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UNNEST(@find_fruits);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
WITH
  `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'aaaa' AS name, ['apple', 'orange', 'grape'] AS fruits
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bbbb' AS name, ['apple', 'orange'] AS fruits
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'cccc' AS name, ['orange', 'grape'] AS fruits
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'dddd' AS name, ['orange'] AS fruits
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'eeee' AS name, ['orange', 'peach'] AS fruits )
SELECT name
FROM `project.dataset.table` 
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(1) 
  FROM UNNEST(fruits) AS fruit 
  WHERE fruit IN ('apple', 'orange')
) >=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and using Scripting functionality of BigQuery

```
#standardSQL 
DECLARE search ARRAY<STRING>;
SET search = ['apple', 'orange'];

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION checkFruits(fruits ARRAY<STRING>, search ARRAY<STRING>) AS (
  ARRAY_LENGTH(search) = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT fruit) 
    FROM UNNEST(fruits) AS fruit 
    WHERE fruit IN UNNEST(search)
  )
);
SELECT name
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE checkFruits(fruits, search)
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row name     
1   aaaa     
2   bbbb
```

In case you you expect list of names as output - you can use below instead of `SELECT name`

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(name, ', ') names
```

in this case - output is

```
Row names    
1   aaaa, bbbb
```